# Laravel 5: directory-elements sort by name in a hasMany relationship

Tags: php, laravel, sorting, directory, relationship

I need to Sort folders ($data['contents']) by relationship langs() where lang_id == 1 How can I do that? Thanks.

In Model Folder:

```
class Folder extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['active', 'date', 'path', 'slug'];

    public function langs()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\LangFolder');
    }

}
```

In Model LangFolder:

```
class LangFolder extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['folder_id', 'lang_id', 'name', 'description'];

    public function folder()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Folder');
    }
}
```

In Controller:

```
public function folders()
{
    // Sort folders ($data['contents']) by relationship langs() where lang_id == 1

    $data['folders'] = Folder::all();
    $data['langs'] = Lang::all();

    $directory = 'library/';
    $elements =  array_diff(scandir($directory), array('..', '.'));

    foreach($elements as $element) {
        if (is_dir($directory . '/' . $element)) {
            $content_element = Folder::where('slug', $element)->first();
            $data['contents'][] = $content_element;
        }
    }

    return view('web.library.index', compact('data'));
}
```

Comment: How about

`Folder::langs()->where('langs.id, '=' 1)->orderBy(FIELD ON LANG)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally added the field "name" of the relationship to the array, and I have converted the array into a collection, and then, I have sorted by 'name' case insensitive. Maybe there is another cleaner solution. This works:

Controller:

```
    foreach($elements as $element){
            if(is_dir($directory.'/'.$element)){
                $content_element = Folder::where('slug', $element)->first();
                $contenidos[] = $content_element;
            }else{
                $data['documents'][] = Document::where('path', $directory.'/'.$element)->first();
            }
        }

   foreach($contenidos as $contenido){
        foreach($contenido->langs as $lang){
            if($lang->lang_id == '1'){
                $contenido->name = $lang->name;
            }
        }
        $data['contents'][]= $contenido;
    }

$data['contents']=collect($data['contents'])->sortBy('name', SORT_NATURAL|SORT_FLAG_CASE);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to order from a relation, you must use `Collection` instead of `Eloquent`, for example:

```
$orderedLangs = $folder->langs->sortBy('lang_id');
```